# Eclipse 2 Error Log Windows open and they can not close problem

Tags: eclipse, logging, window

There is problem in my Eclipse. There are two twin Error Log windows and I can not close either of them.

It completely makes trolling on my development windows. When I want to open a class the codes go under the windows.

[image: Screenshot of error windows]

Comment: Hi there. What happens when you close Eclipse and then open it again?

Comment: Does _Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective_ fix it? By the way, your Eclipse seems to be outdated.

Comment: Yes After your comment when I tried  Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective it completely worked. Thanks a lot!!